# Predicting user ratings

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-science

I have a prediction problem that I am working on and need some help on how to approach it. I have a CSV with two columns, user_id and ratings, where a user is  giving a rating on something in the ratings column. A user can repeat in the user_id column with different unique ratings. For example:

```
user_id    rating
1          5
4          6
1          6
7          6
2          7
4          7
```

Now the prediction data set has users who have already given previous rating similar to the one above:

```
user_id    rating
11         6
12         10
13         8
13         9
14         4
14         5
```

Goal is to predict what these specific users will rate the next time. Secondly, lets say if we add a user '15' with no rating history, how can we predict the first two ratings that user will provide, in order.

I'm not sure how to train a model, with just user_id and ratings, which also happens to be the target column. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and the foremost thing that you have to mention that on what a user is giving rating i.e., the category for example in movie rating system you can provide that for a particular movie A which is an action movie the user gives rating 1 which means that the user hates action and for a movie B which is comedy type the user gives rating 9 which means that the user is a comedy lover so the next time a similar category came you can predict the rating of the user very easily and you can do so by including many movie category like thriller,romance,drama etc and can even take many accounting features like movie length, leading actor, director, language etc etc as all these govern a user rating very broadly.

But if you not provide on which basis the user is giving rating then it is very hard and of no use for example I am a user and I give ratings like 1,5,2,6,8,1,9,3,4,10 can you predict my next rating the answer is no because it just like a random generator between 0-10 but in the movie case where my past ratings clearly show that I love comedy and hate action then when a new comedy movie came you can easily predict the rating for that movie for me.

But still if your problem is this only then you can use various statistical methods like either take the mean and then approximate to nearest integer or either take the mode.

But I can suggest is that plot the rating for a user and visualise it, if it is following some pattern like for a user the rating first increases then goes to peak then decreases then go to minimum and then increases and follow like this(believe me this is going to be very impractical due to your constraints) and on the basis of that predict the rating.

But the best out of all these is be make a statistical model like give high weight to the last rating and lesser weight to second last rating  and then even lesser and then take a mean, eg->

predict_rating = w1*(last_rating) + w2*(second_last_rating) + w3*(third_last_rating) ....

and then take mean

This will give you very good results and indeed it is **machine learning** and this particular algorithm in which you find the best suited weights is **multivariate linear regression**

and this for sure is the best model for the given constraints

Comment: Thanks for the input, it is sort of a pattern problem where I have to predict what the rating will be next for a given user, using the trend or pattern learned from the previous users.

Comment: The linear regression model I mentioned will do the job well